# The order of the item for get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a Python dataframe that includes a comma separated value.

```
 ID  Items            Random
  1  K93,J11,W34,Z38  38
  2  J11,M88          487
  3  T44,P03,M88      314
  4  K93,P03,D32      79
  5  M88,Z38,E49      33
  6                   443
```

When I try to one-hot-encode it I face problem that it preserve its location.

I mean for item K93 it shows in ID 1 and ID 4 and for both it is the first item

Once I use get_dummies it will only appear one time as in both records it is the first.

While for M88 it shows in IDs 2,3 and 5 with order 2,3 and 1

So it shows 3 times in the get_dummies

```
  ID            Items Random  Items_  Items_J11  Items_K93  Items_M88  Items_T44  Items_J11  Items_M88  Items_P03  Items_Z38  Items_D32  Items_E49  Items_M88  Items_W34  Items_Z38
0  1  K93,J11,W34,Z38     38       0          0          1          0          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          1          1
1  2          J11,M88    487       0          1          0          0          0          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
2  3      T44,P03,M88    314       0          0          0          0          1          0          0          1          0          0          0          1          0          0
3  4      K93,P03,D32     79       0          0          1          0          0          0          0          1          0          1          0          0          0          0
4  5      M88,Z38,E49     33       0          0          0          1          0          0          0          0          1          0          1          0          0          0
5  6                     443       1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
```

Is there a way to make items shows only once in the get_dummies?

The results should be like this

```
  ID            Items Random  Items_J11  Items_K93  Items_M88  Items_T44  Items_P03  Items_D32  Items_E49  Items_W34  Items_Z38
0  1  K93,J11,W34,Z38     38          1          1          0          0          0          0          0          1          1
1  2          J11,M88    487          1          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0
2  3      T44,P03,M88    314          0          0          1          1          1          0          0          0          0
3  4      K93,P03,D32     79          0          1          0          0          1          1          0          0          0
4  5      M88,Z38,E49     33          0          0          1          0          0          0          1          0          1
5  6                     443          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
```

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','Items','Random'])

df = df.append({
     "ID": "1",
     "Items":  "K93,J11,W34,Z38",
     "Random": "38"
      }, ignore_index=True)

df = df.append({
     "ID": "2",
     "Items":  "J11,M88",
     "Random": "487"
      }, ignore_index=True)


df = df.append({
     "ID": "3",
     "Items":  "T44,P03,M88",
     "Random": "314"
      }, ignore_index=True)


df = df.append({
     "ID": "4",
     "Items":  "K93,P03,D32",
     "Random": "79"
      }, ignore_index=True)


df = df.append({
     "ID": "5",
     "Items":  "M88,Z38,E49",
     "Random": "33"
      }, ignore_index=True)

df = df.append({
     "ID": "6",
     "Items":  "",
     "Random": "443"
      }, ignore_index=True)

df1 = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['Items'].str.split(",", expand=True),prefix = 'Items').astype(np.int8)], axis=1)

print(df1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max` if need output 0 and 1 or `sum` if need count `1` values:

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df['Items'].str.split(",", expand=True), prefix = 'Items')
         .max(level=0, axis=1)
         .astype(np.int8))
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print(df)
  ID            Items Random  Items_  Items_J11  Items_K93  Items_M88  \
0  1  K93,J11,W34,Z38     38       0          1          1          0   
1  2          J11,M88    487       0          1          0          1   
2  3      T44,P03,M88    314       0          0          0          1   
3  4      K93,P03,D32     79       0          0          1          0   
4  5      M88,Z38,E49     33       0          0          0          1   
5  6                     443       1          0          0          0   

   Items_T44  Items_P03  Items_Z38  Items_D32  Items_E49  Items_W34  
0          0          0          1          0          0          1  
1          0          0          0          0          0          0  
2          1          1          0          0          0          0  
3          0          1          0          1          0          0  
4          0          0          1          0          1          0  
5          0          0          0          0          0          0
```

If large data then [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) should be better choice:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Items'].str.split(',')), 
                   columns='Items_' + mlb.classes_)
#print (df1)

df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print(df)
  ID            Items Random  Items_  Items_D32  Items_E49  Items_J11  \
0  1  K93,J11,W34,Z38     38       0          0          0          1   
1  2          J11,M88    487       0          0          0          1   
2  3      T44,P03,M88    314       0          0          0          0   
3  4      K93,P03,D32     79       0          1          0          0   
4  5      M88,Z38,E49     33       0          0          1          0   
5  6                     443       1          0          0          0   

   Items_K93  Items_M88  Items_P03  Items_T44  Items_W34  Items_Z38  
0          1          0          0          0          1          1  
1          0          1          0          0          0          0  
2          0          1          1          1          0          0  
3          1          0          1          0          0          0  
4          0          1          0          0          0          1  
5          0          0          0          0          0          0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first split the string and stack the list then apply get_dummies.

```
(
    df.Items.str.split(',').apply(pd.Series).stack()
    .pipe(pd.get_dummies, prefix='Items')
    .sum(level=0)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that pandas does not provide an explode (to row) function in versions before `0.25.0` but neithertheless we can get the desired result. First split and expand the DataFrame then stack it to have all information in one column. Stacking produces a multiindex from which we only need level 
`0` and therefore we drop the unwanted part. `s` is now the exploded column `Items`. From there we straightforwardly produce dummies and concatenate it back to its original frame. We need to groupby and sum because otherwise we would have the appearing duplicated Item rows where each row only contains one true dummy

```
s = df.Items.str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(1)
pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(pd.concat([df, s], 1)[0])], 1).groupby(['ID', 'Items', 'Random']).sum().reset_index()
```

result

```
    ID      Items               Random      D32 E49 J11 K93 M88 P03 T44 W34 Z38
0   1       K93,J11,W34,Z38     38      0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1
1   2       J11,M88             487     0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
2   3       T44,P03,M88         314     0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0
3   4       K93,P03,D32         79      0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
4   5       M88,Z38,E49         33      0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
5   6                           443     1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: This is great solution for the example i provided, but my real dataset it 1M+ records and pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(pd.concat([df, s], 1)[0])], 1) will make it extremely big

Comment: That produces `sum(id*#items)` entries. which leads to a factor 4 or 5 if the provided example is realistic. You're right but I don't see a way around this. Maybe using pandas 0.25.0's [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)